# Python PUT call fails while curl call doesn't

Tags: python, python-requests

Best wishes (first things first!)

I want to enable/disable a PoE port on my UniFi switch. For this I aim using Python 3.9.1 (first time) with the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

gateway = {"ip": "MYSERVER.COM", "port": "8443"}
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

login_url = f"https://{gateway['ip']}:{gateway['port']}/api/login"
login_data = {
    "username": "MYUSERNAME",
    "password": "MYPASSWORD"
}

session = requests.Session()
login_response = session.post(login_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(login_data), verify=False)

if (login_response.status_code == 200):
    api_url_portoverrides = 'api/s/default/rest/device/MYDEVICEID'
    poe_url = f"https://{gateway['ip']}:{gateway['port']}/{api_url_portoverrides}"
    # build json for port overrides
    json_poe_state_on = '{"port_overrides": [{"port_idx": 6, "portconf_id": "MYPROFILE1"}]}'
    json_poe_state_off = '{"port_overrides": [{"port_idx": 6, "portconf_id": "MYPROFILE2"}]}'
    post_response = session.put(poe_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(json_poe_state_off))   
    print('Response HTTP Request {request}'.format(request=post_response.request ))
else:
    print("Login failed")
```

The login works (I get the 2 security cookies and tried them in Paw (a macOS REST API client) to see if these were ok)) but the second call, the. PUT, returns OK but noting happens.
Before I've done this in Python, I tried all my calls in Paw first and there it works. I tried everything in bash with curl and there it works too. So I am a bit at a loss here.

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you for your time!

Best regards!
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! By looking into what was posted with Wireshark I saw that the payload was different. The culprit was the json.dumps function which encoded the string by putting a backslash in front of each double quote.
It works now!